# Is there any way to launch my application right away without 'Ok Google"?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, voice-recognition

I've searched about launching my app with voice. And what I got is `using Ok Google`. However, I don't want this feature but start my app right a way without calling `Ok Google`. Instead, `Hey, XXX` Then, launch my app.

Maybe I can accomplish this feature by getting a permission of using microphone and using service of my app. In this way, At least my app will launch, if the user once launched my app during the device is on. Maybe using `startActivity()`?

Is it possible or not? If it is yes, What do I need to do to achieve this result?

Comment: This is not possible unless you've your own voice assistant

Comment: It is not possible unless you design your own assistant as you will need all necessary permissions to launch an app.

Comment: How can I make my own voice assistant? Is it against the rule of Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible** to launch your app using your own customized name like  **Hey Jarvis , open XYZ app.**

You can only use the following commands in your android mobiles to launch your app.

***Hey Google, open Facebook***
or
***Ok Google, open Facebook***

The prefix, Ok Google / Hey Google are proprietary to Google's Voice Assistant that comes handy in Android mobiles. So we cannot change them as our wish, may be we can expect the something like you asked in future. But not sure.

**You can refer to the google thread related to this [here](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/1057203?hl=en)**

As mentioned in the comments, you need to design your own voice assistant to do so. Even if you are developing your own voice assistance, not sure you can run them on your mobiles.

**Edited**

> Maybe I can accomplish this feature by getting a permission of using microphone and using service of my app. In this way, At least my app will launch, if the user once launched my app during the device is on. Maybe using startActivity()?

You can use in-app voice features when your app is in foreground. You can give a try to this [Google Actions on Android apps](https://developers.google.com/actions/app/). Though this feature is new and limited, you can gain some idea regarding this.